# Getting "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" when deploying war alltough using jdk 1.6

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I'm having issues with deploying the war file on tomcat 7.0.47 the traget jdk must be 1.6. Initially I wrote my classes on jdk 1.7 but then I recompiled the WAR file and the jar containing the problematic class using jdk1.6.41 and also changed the project facets . I'm getting this when I try to start the server

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: jdbcHandler/JDBCZhoarHandler : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class jdbcHandler.JDBCZhoarHandler)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2922)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

Could it be it has something to do with the driver? (I use mysql driver 5.0.8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the tomcat version. I changed to 7.0.39 and problem solved, although I have no idea why

Answer (score 1):

The class `jdbcHandler.JDBCZhoarHandler` is still using a 1.7 build; you didn't get the recompiled file packaged up.

Comment: I probebly missing an obvious action. I changed the facets, compiler and buildpath to 1.6 and it still does not work.

Comment: The problem was with the tomcat version. I changed to 7.0.39 and problem solved